# Is there a word you can use to mean "changing something to fit another purpose"?

Tags: word-request

I am thinking repurposing, but that's not really a word, and it doesn't seem to be appropriate when talking about a company, so is there a way to say it a little better?

For example:

> Disney wanted to repurpose Pixar into a game development company.

Comment: repurpose is fine; retrofit, for a machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Repurpose* is absolutely a word, and not at all inappropriate to use about a company. You could, however, also use *refocus*, *reinvent*, or *reorient*, all of which are (obviously) metaphorical.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I just saw entries for repurpose in a couple of online dictionaries. So it seems that it is a word. But if repurpose doesn't fit your purpose, what about reinvent?"

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/reinvent

example: Acme Widget Corporation reinvented itself by moving from making kitchen utensils to manufacturing computer disk drives.